# Spring MVC error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring-mvc

My error in eclipse console is

```
[WARN ] PageNotFound.noHandlerFound() - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/student-data/status/student/10] in DispatcherServlet with name student-detail
```

In the browser on calling the url `http://localhost:8080/student-data/status/student/10` I am getting HTTP Status 404. the requested resource is not available

There are around 3 questions answered on almost same title and I went through all of them. but it seems the issue here is different. I am getting the error mentioned in title and below is my Spring MVC configuration files

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>student-detail</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/status/student</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>student-detail</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/status/student/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am getting the pages using the /status/student because the list of students is getting populated
But not getting details of a individual student when using /status/student/*

The controller used for getting list of student shown below is working perfectly fine and all the students list is populated

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudentList(ModelMap model) {
       // code
        return "studentList";
}
```

But when I am using the getStudentDetail() method in the controller I am getting the error in the Eclipse console

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudentDetail(@PathVariable String id,ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("The Id is :"+id);
            return "studentDetail";
    }
```

ERROR is:

```
 [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet.doService() - DispatcherServlet with name 'student-detail' processing GET request for [/student-data/status/student/10]
[25 Aug 2014 10:22:21,336] [DEBUG] RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal() - Looking up handler method for path /10
[25 Aug 2014 10:22:21,338] [DEBUG] RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal() - Did not find handler method for [/10]
[25 Aug 2014 10:22:21,338] [WARN ] PageNotFound.noHandlerFound() - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/student-data/status/student/10] in DispatcherServlet with name 'student-detail'
```

studentList.jsp contains

```
<c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="studentList">
    <tr onclick="location.href='../status/student/${studentList.UUID}'">
      <td><c:out value="${studentList.UUID}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${studentList.userName}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Does `studentDetail` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is for wildcard matches, the servlet isn't forwarding the prefix along to the controller match, meaning its' just truncating the "/status/student/" and only forwarding the /10.

If you want it to match, you can make the initial mapping broad and just use spring mvc mappings to route from there (that's what I do)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>student-detail</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you just add the verbosity to your controllers

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/status/student")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudentList(ModelMap model) {...}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudentDetail(@PathVariable String id,ModelMap model) {...}
    ...

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

See section 16.3.2

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me. I removed all url-pattern and just used.            <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>student-detail</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/status/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>